# Scroll and zoom in google-map not works when fitToMarkers is set

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polymer

Im new at polymer and try to show some markers in the `google-map` polymer element.
I wish that when the map is rendered the user will see all markers in the first view. For this the attribute `fitToMarkers` works fine.

But when I set this flag my map isn't scrollable (i.e. drag to the left or right in the map) and the zoom with the mouse don't works too.

Anybody knows a workaround?

Here's is my cuttet code:

```
    <polymer-element name="my-map">
      <template>
    <style>    

      :host {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #google_map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
      }
      </style>
    <mobileme-service-locations id="service" locations="{{locations}}"></mobileme-service-locations>

    <!--Wait until locations are loaded-->
    <template if="{{locations}}">
        <!--render google map-->
        <google-map id="google_map" fitToMarkers="true">
            <!--iterate over all locations and add them as marker to the map-->
            <template repeat="{{entry in locations}}">
                <google-map-marker
                    latitude="{{entry.lat}}"
                    longitude="{{entry.lng}}"
                    draggable="false">

                    <!--create the window which appear if user click on marker--
                    <!--..........-->
                </google-map-marker>
            </template>
        </google-map>
    </template> 
  </template>

<script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        //...
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

The mobileme-service-locations loads locations..

Comment: Where is your code? No-one can help without seeing your code!

Comment: Hi MrUpsidown. Sorry, for that. I thought this is a general problem with the flag "fitToMarkers" and my specific code is not relevant for my question. I edited my question.

Comment: You might be right about the fact that it is a general *problem* with `fitToMarkers` (is it a problem or a feature btw?) but anyway it's always better to show your code. I don't see a "scrollable" attribute but maybe you can try with `zoomable` and see if it does any better. Otherwise, you might need to drop the `fitToMarkers` attribute and calculate the appropriate center and zoom level by yourself.

Comment: showCenterMarker attribute, in place of fitToMarkers,  will make the map scrollable. Maybe that will fit for you case. 

Here is my google-map playground if it can help: http://plnkr.co/edit/oQv2sPHBirN8FGlcrXTP?p=preview